# Add matrix to all slices in an array

Tags: r

This seems like a very basic R question, but had some difficulty adding a matrix to all slices in an array (actually an image stack, and before anyone asks, there is a reason I want to do this in R).  As an example I want to add the matrix sampleMean to all the slices in the third dimension of combinedAtten:

```
combinedAtten <- array(rexp(300), dim = c(10, 10, 3))
sampleMean <- matrix(rep(1:2, 50), ncol = 10)
distortedMask <- apply(combinedAtten, 3, function(x)x + sampleMean)
dim(distortedMask)
```

Unexpectedly, the output is a matrix with dims [100, 3], not an array with dims [10, 10, 3].  I have a clumsy solution of using simplify = F, then combining the list back into an array, as follows:

```
distortedMask <- apply(combinedAtten, 3, function(x)x + sampleMean, simplify = F)
distortedMask <- array(unlist(distortedMask), dim = dim(combinedAtten))
dim(distortedMask)
```

Just as a learning exercise, I am curious as to why apply reshapes the array in the first place, and whether there is slightly less clumsy solution than using apply to create a list, unlisting it, then recreating the array from the resulting vector.

Comment: Did `apply` get a `simplify` argument in the last version of R. I doesn't exist in version 4.0.4

Comment: I'm using Version 4.1.0.  Never occurred to me that simplify might be a new addition.

Comment: yes @IRTFM, [new feature R 4.1.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to `replicate` the 'sampleMean' to make the dimensions same and add (`+`)

```
distoredMask <- combinedAtten + replicate(dim(combinedAtten)[3], sampleMean)
```

NOTE: By default `replicate` uses `simplify = "array"`

-check the `dim`

```
> all.equal(dim(combinedAtten), dim(distoredMask))
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or if we want to use the OP's method, then another option is wrap with `simplify2array` on the `list` output

```
distoredMask2 <- simplify2array(apply(combinedAtten, 3,
     function(x)x + sampleMean, simplify = FALSE))
```

-checking

```
> dim(distoredMask2)
[1] 10 10  3
> identical(distoredMask, distoredMask2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Now that I understand what the goal was, I can suggest that all you needed to do was alter the dimension of the result you had constructed that was 100 x 3

```
dim(distortedMask) <- c(10,10,3)
dim(distortedMask)
#[1] 10 10  3
```

This succeeds because a matrix or array is just an atomic vector to which a dimension attribute has been applied. It would fail if you wanted the ordering of the result to be different in which case the `aperm` function might be needed.

You could have added just 3 copies to the original matrix as well, since adding a vector of the proper length to a matrix or array preserves the dimension attribute.

---

Prior off target suggestion:

```
identical(distortedMask, combinedAtten + c(sampleMean,sampleMean,sampleMean) )
[1] TRUE
```

'
See if `abind` in the abind package is what you want:

```
> library(abind)
> str(abind(combinedAtten,sampleMean))
 num [1:10, 1:10, 1:4] 0.862 0.639 0.3 0.193 0.259 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : NULL
```

That looks like what I think you wanted, so try:

```
 distortedMask <- abind(combinedAtten,sampleMean) # after library(abind)
```

Comment: Doesn't do what I was after, but abind is a useful suggestion for rbind/cbind for arrays.

Comment: @Knackiedoo  So all you wanted to do was change the dimension attribute?

Comment: Redimensioning the output using dim( ) <-  is an interesting little trick to remember, thank you.  +1.